# after creating objects and adding them to a list , later when accessing each object's attributes, its not there

Tags: swift, list, custom-cell

after creating multiple objects of a viewcontroller which includes a tableview with custom cells then adding them in a list , when I try to access them through the list to set the values of the cells and label of each viewcontroller its just not there , if I add a delay as seen with a value equal to 0.0  miracuiolsly it works , I am so confused and would appreciate any indictors to what might be the problem, calling populate() without the delay gives an out of index error indicating that the cells are not created yet they are created[ here is a snip of my code]

```
func createObjects() -> Void {
    for i in 0...self.cardcount-1 {
        var localObject=ViewController2(cellcount: cellcount[i], cardindex: i)
        self.customviews.append(localObject)
    } // end of for loop

    for i in 0...self.cardcount-1 {
        for j in 0...self.cellcount[i]-1 {
            var Mydata : String = self.response["schedule"][i]["time_frames"][j]["start_time"].stringValue
            let index = Mydata.index(Mydata.endIndex, offsetBy: -3)
            Mydata = Mydata.substring(to: index)
            self.customviews[i].setarray(L: Mydata, X: j)
            self.customviews[i].setlabol(L: self.response["schedule"][i]["day_of_week"].stringValue)
        } // end of j loop
    } // end of iloop

    let delay = 0.0
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: delay, target: self, selector: #selector(populate), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    self.display(array: self.customviews)

} //end of create objects
```

Comment: When are you initialising `self.custonviews`.

Comment: please format your code, its really hard to read

Comment: var customviews = [ViewController2]() as a global variable